# Passing Admin Credentials to run process in windows form (c#)

Tags: c#, winforms, process

I am trying to run a process by passing admin username and password, but the code throws an error. If I trying commenting out the username and password of admin, code works perfectly but prompts for username and password to run the process. I am trying to make the process run without user need to enter the credentials.

Have anyone tried same. Could someone provide resolution to this error.

Here is my code that starts the process.

```
 private void UpdateApplication(string tempFilePath, string currentPath, string newPath, string launchArgs)
        {
            string password = "testpass"; 
            SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray())
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }

            string argument = "/C Choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 4 & Del /F /Q \"{0}\" & Choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 2 & Move /Y \"{1}\" \"{2}\" & Start \"\" /D \"{3}\" \"{4}\" {5}";
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
            info.Arguments = string.Format(argument, currentPath, tempFilePath, newPath, Path.GetDirectoryName(newPath), Path.GetFileName(newPath), launchArgs);
            info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;
            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            info.UserName = "test";   //admin User
            info.Password = securePassword;  // admin Password
            info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            info.Verb = "runas";
            Process.Start(info);

       }
```

And this is the error that is coming up. (*Note the error doesn't come up if I comment out info.Username and info.Password.)

[image]

Comment: Is the directory accessable for the specified user? At my work, I always run in trouble when I want to run a program as Administrator if the program is located on a mapped network drive.

Comment: Yes. The directory is in the "Program Files" and test user is admin and have access to Program Files

Comment: Try shorten your argument chain for debug purposes. Start with `/C Choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 4 & Del /F /Q \"{0}\"` and see what happens. If this code runs without errors, add the rest of your arguments step by step. Then tell us at which step the error occurs.